# Problems with KBDLL hooking

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm trying to build my own keylogger (private/educational) to extend my skills.
I started looking into hooks and in this case the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code but it doesn't work.
What I do is:

- Create the callback function with an nCode, wParam and lParam plus a return to  CallNextHookEx.
- I set the function in the HHOOK handle with SetWindowsHookEx and put in an infinite loop. My KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT is set to *lParam, as lParam is a pointer to a KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT containing the information I want, right?

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

HHOOK hookHandle;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookData;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nC, WPARAM wP, LPARAM lP);
std::string readLogs();
void writeLogs(std::string logs);

int main()
{
    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    while(true) {

        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

std::string readLogs() {
    std::ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("logs.txt");
    std::string logs;
    readFile >> logs;
    return logs;
}

void writeLogs(std::string logs) {
    std::string oLogs = readLogs();
    std::ofstream writeFile;
    writeFile.open("logs.txt");
    writeFile << oLogs + logs;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nC, WPARAM wP, LPARAM lP) {
    if (nC >= 0) {
        if (wP == WM_KEYDOWN) {
            hookData = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lP);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nC, wP, lP);
}
```

Just ignore the readLogs() and writeLogs().

I thought the problem was with the:

```
hookData = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lP);
```

But that wasn't the case apparently, because a simple increment of int x didn't happen.

Thus I came here to ask for help. What can I do to fix my problem?

Comment: Where is this alleged increment of x?

Comment: [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543.aspx)

Comment: @EricBrown Here you go: http://pastebin.com/pSQ3mSs1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the documentation. Straight from [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx):

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you maybe point me in a direction? I've changed the while(true){ } loop to a message loop but it only works when I add a message box to the callback function. And I'd rather not have a message box pop up after every key. What different kind of 'messages' can I use? I've tried SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, NULL, wP, lP) but nothing happens.

Comment: @Flinzy: All you need is a standard message loop (without any filters). See [Using Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928.aspx) for an example.